# React and Google Translate Script workaround without window.location.reload

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, google-translate

So, I've somehow managed to implement Google Translate into React using the following script:

```
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" async></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
          {
            pageLanguage: "en",
            layout:
              window.google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
          },
          "google_translate_element"
        );
      }
    </script>
```

This script is free and doesn't require any API-key, so it's great to use. There are 3 issues, and I have managed to fix 2 of them.

1. The first problem is that it has a sticky bar that changes the language. The sticky bar however did not fit the current UI, so I needed to hide it. This was easily done by hiding it using CSS.
2. Since the sticky bar is hidden, I needed to find a way to change the language using React. I've managed to do so using the following code:
   **App.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

const App = () => {
  const cookies = Cookies();
  const googtrans = cookies.get("googtrans");
  const languageCode = googtrans.split('/')[2];
  const [code, setCode] = useState(languageCode);

  const setGoogleTrans = () => {
    document.cookie = "googtrans=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
    cookies.set("googtrans", `/en/${code}`, {
      domain: `${window.location.hostname}`,
      path: "/",
    });
    window.location.reload();
  };

  useEffect(()=>{
    setGoogleTrans();
  },[code])

  return <button 
      onClick={() => setCode(code === 'en' ? 'tl' : 'en')}
    >
      Change language
    </button>
}
```

3. The problem with this however is that I still need a `window.location.reload()` in order for Google Translate to kick in.

Is there a way for it to translate once setGoogleTrans without needing to use `window.location.reload()`?

Answer (score 0):

Put the logic into a custom hook.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function useGoogleTranslateScript() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const addScript = document.createElement('script');
        addScript.setAttribute(
            'src',
            '//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'
        );
        document.body.appendChild(addScript);
        // debugger
        window.googleTranslateElementInit = () => {
            new window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
                {
                    pageLanguage: 'en',
                    autoDisplay: true,
                },
                'google_translate_element'
            );
        };
    }, []);
}

export default useGoogleTranslateScript;
```

And make sure bind the googleTranslate to a higher component (for example the navbar), this way only run once and avoid create multiple script, divs, and iframe.